# How to make two Package.swift in a root directory?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

[image: MyRepo-picture]

As shown in the picture，I have a repo named MyRepo, MyRepo's Source divided into two parts, ARepo and BRepo.BRepo depends on ARepo.

When I use Cocoapods, I can make two podspec file, named ARepo.podspec and BRepo.podspec respectively.In ARepo.podsepc, s.source_files = 'Source/ARepo/**'. In BRepo.podsepc, s.source_files = 'Source/BRepo/**'.
But Now I want to support Swift Package Manager.

I read the SPM documentation and search using Google, but I don't find anything help.

I know If I make two git repo, It can resolve this problem in some way, but that's not what I want.
What should I do？

Comment: Cocopods and Swift Packages behave differently. Create ARepo separately. Then create BRepo and make it depend on ARepo. Then your final project can depend on BRepo and can also have a direct dependancy on ARepo.

Comment: That seems to be the only way. Thank you